# Is it necessary to follow typing schemes when coding?

Tags: keyboard, typing

I found It OK to follow [typing schemes](http://www.holborntraining.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Keyboard-Illustrator.png) when typing sentences like these I'm typing at the moment
but i'm not sure if It would help me when coding
for example when typing In JavaScript you lots of letters like `: ; ' " = + , *` and if you're using jQuery you'd type the `$` sign in almost each line
and It's a bit hard at least for me

also when using text editors that have **auto complete** It become's more different with normal typing

Is any famous programmer using these typing schemes?
or all the programmers just type as I do
does It help at all to follow these schemes?

Is there any typing scheme designed for programming?


thanks

Comment: Are you talking about keyboard layouts? I'm not really sure what you mean by "typing schemes", and a colored image of a keyboard doesn't help. If you're looking for a "programmer's" keyboard layout, check out something like [Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/), though learning a new keyboard layout takes quite a while. Though if you can edit your question to add more details, that'd help a lot for me to parse what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not talking about *keyboard layouts* at all, It's all about typing with 10 fingers , [take a look](http://www.ratatype.com/)

Comment: Errr, I'd say it falls to personal preference. Touch typing (being able to type with all ten fingers [thumbs typically reserved for space, but depending on personal preference] without having to look at the keyboard) is typical for experienced typists, but I'm not really sure what else could be done to change how you type without changing the keyboard layout.

Comment: I just changed the image for *typing schemes* , you'd just try to press *W* letter with your index finger for example, or anything else , the picture I linked Is recommended for typists and I want to know If there Is anything same for programmers or It's OK for programmers too

Comment: Okay. So just which finger corresponds to which keys on the keyboard. For the most part, it's the same. Those fingers in those positions on the keyboard are what's typically most comfortable for most people. There's probably no _standard_ alternative finger layouts, and even if there were, they probably wouldn't increase programmer effectiveness, whereas changing keyboard layout can put more commonly-used keys in easier to reach positions. Overall, probably not, and to be completely honest, Stack Overflow probably isn't the best place to ask, as it's more for specific programming questions.

Comment: may be you're right , but there are many question about typing speed and even ways to type a specific letter , I hope someone could answer completely